# Optimize a function's code with repeated treatment

Tags: angular

I have this function which is used to get the news of a selected category. The first if case test if the category is indeed in the category's array as well as if it's not of type `'All'` and then push the category's news into an `getNewsByCategory`. The second if case test if the category is of type 'All' and push all the categories's new into `getNewsByCategory`.

If you notice in the two if cases there is the same code and i want to optimize it please

```
  getNewsByCategory(category) {
    const getNewsByCategory = [];
    if (this.newsCategory) {
      this.newsCategory.forEach(element => {
        if (element.category === category && category !== 'All') {
          element.news.filter(n => {
            getNewsByCategory.push(n);
          });
        } else if (category === 'All') {
          element.news.filter(n => {
            getNewsByCategory.push(n);
          });
        }
      });
      return getNewsByCategory;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the combination of those two `if`s:

```
if (element.category === category || category === 'All')
```

Comment: FYI, it will only check the second test, if the first fails. So the (or) || operator can be used to set default values, as it also works on truthy/falsy values.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, and I think you're misusing the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function since it should be used with a returned boolean in order to create a new array with only the values that match a condition.
Plus you can use the spread operator (...) in the push function in order to push all the element.news.
Anyway:

```js
  getNewsByCategory(category) {
    if (this.newsCategory) {
      return this.newsCategory.reduce(
        (newsByCategory, element) => (element.category === category || category === 'All') && newsByCategory.push(...element.news),
        []
      );
    }
  }
```